# Right on through meaning

Tags: phrase-meaning

The following sentence is given:

> Instead of going back by the same route he took the Jones Beach
>   Causeway *right on through* to the town of Merrick and onto the
>   Meadowbrok Parkway until he reached the Nothern State Parkway.

I'm interesting in the meaing of *right on through*. Explain what that meanss, please.

Comment: [Adverbial sense 10](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/right+on): Used as an intensive: *kept right on going*. Somewhat akin to the Russian "прямехонько".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Straight through without stopping, deviating from his route, or changing roads

He traveled from point A to point B on the same road in a single, unbroken journey.

Answer (score 1):

*continuing through*:

> Instead of going back by the same route he took the Jones Beach Causeway, **continuing** through to the town of Merrick and onto the Meadowbrok Parkway, until he reached the Nothern State Parkway.

(commas just to break up the sentence a bit, not required.)